# Meaning of Either

Tags: logic, formal-proofs

I can't figure out what is meant in my text books with the "Either / Or" statements. I'm in a math proof class trying to wrap my head around this. See example below.

```
Either Jim or Bob has red hair
P = Jim has red hair
Q = Bob has red hair
```

Does this mean:

```
P v Q
```

or

```
(P v Q) ^ (~P v ~Q)
```

Thanks

Comment: I understand it looks like a duplicate. I guess it's ambiguous in english, as I've seen it used both ways.

Comment: In formal logic, you would generally translate it to just OR, rather than XOR. So the "either" has no formal meaning. But in practice, in natural language mathematics it is ambiguous whether the "either" is meant to imply that only one case can hold.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to get confused. Imagine what any person who has not studied mathematics beyond high school would understand by this statement. It is exactly that.

Comment: In my experience, `either P or Q` is an ambiguous English sentence, sometimes meaning `P or Q` and sometimes meaning `P xor Q`.

Comment: @ZevChonoles: True. But in introductory logic, this is the meaning and one need split hair for a simple thing while there are enough confusing things at an advanced stage